Book series about a teenage girl who finds out that magic is real and is sent to her grandmother's magic school
The book series talks about a "normal" teenage girl who gets back home after spending the day with friends and her mother sends her to a magic school with a stranger, after explaining to her that magic is real. She finds out later that the manager of the school is her grandmother and her mother is on the run as part of the resistance against the magic council. After a while, she finds out that her father, who was presumed dead, is still alive and also part of the resistance.
The rest of the books talk about her fight to survive the magic council, another evil mastermind that needs her magic, and her learning about her abilities.

Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books?

I am not able to recall but i guess it was around 5-10 years.

just looked at School of Necessary Magic series/universe, sadly it is not what i am looking for.

A quick Google search turned up the School of Magic Survival series by Chloe Garner.
I've not read it but reading some of the blurbs in the series it seems to fit.

If Valerie is going to learn how to use magic, she must first learn how to survive it.
Valerie grew up a normal girl. In high school, she was popular, smart, happy.
But all that changes when her mother's former life - a life kept hidden from Valerie - collides into Valerie's reality.
Forced to walk away from everything she's always known, Valerie finds herself in a magic school where she may be protected, but she certainly isn't liked.
Facing classmates who resent her for being there and a faculty who are caught up in the same secret war that threatened her mother, Valerie is going to have to flourish or perish in her new reality.

From Fantastic Fiction

Surviving Magic (2019)
Unveiling Magic (2019)
Real Magic (2019)
Shadow Magic (2021)
Battle Magic (2021)
Magic Unleashed (2021)
Blood Magic (2021)



thank you, for some reason it didn't come up when i searched on google
